# Export-CSV showing System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String] for Azure Tags?

Tags: azure, powershell

My script using Get-AzDisk https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azdisk?view=azps-5.9.0 like below

```
Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName|Where-Object{$_.ManagedBy.Length -lt 1} | Select-Object Name, OsType, DiskSizeGB, ResourceGroupName, Location, Tags, Tier, ProvisioningState, TimeCreated | ogv
```

Cannot export the actual Tags values like in the Out-GridView does:

[image]

This is the .CSV column for Tags:

[image]

How to modify it so it can show the same data as in the OGV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a **[calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)** to format the object (which is a hashtable) to the desired output. Here is an example that uses an calculated property to serialize the tags as JSON:

```
Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName 
| Where-Object { $_.ManagedBy.Length -lt 1 } 
| Select-Object Name, OsType, DiskSizeGB, ResourceGroupName, Location, @{e = {$_.Tags | ConvertTo-Json | Out-String}; l='Tags'} , Tier, ProvisioningState, TimeCreated
```

And here the corresponding output as CSV (after I pipe it to [`ConvertTo-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7.1&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) cmdlet):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tags are a Hash.

```
$myTags = $vm.Tags
if($myTags) {
    foreach ($key in $myTags.Keys) {
        $curVal = $myTags[$key]
    }
}
```

You can grab all the Keys and Values and write them to a string in the column.
Be aware the $curVal could itself be a multi-value system.collections.generic.dictionary and might require further manipulation.